# Objects with indexed constituent parts

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question

Is there any existing research about objects which have indexed constituent parts?

Example: The formula $1+(2-3)$ has $1$, $2-3$, $+$ as its parts.

I am asking about a general theory, not limited only to finite or only to acyclic objects.

I ask for a reference to check if my research on this topic is novel (and maybe to add references to make it publishable).

[Here are my research drafts.](http://www.mathematics21.org/formulas.html)

Comment: See [Parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I met parse trees before. You can see that in my theory I deal with more general objects than parse trees